# php facebook login array merge error

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, array-merge

i am trying to intugrate facebook login to my site, the error i am getting is:

```
array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #2 is not an array
Filename: fb/base_facebook.php

Line Number: 529
```

the code i using in my controller is:

```
$this->load->library('fb');
$data = array
    (
        'redirect_uri'=>site_url('main/handle_facebook_login'),
        'scope'=>'email'

    );

$this->fb->sdk->getLoginUrl('$data');
```

getLoginUrl is where it throws the exemption

the code in fb library is:

```
class Fb {

private $appid = '';
private $secret = '';

public function __construct()
{
  $ci =& get_instance();
  $ci->config->load('fb');
  $this->appid = $ci->config->item('fb_appid');
  $this->secret = $ci->config->item('fb_secret');

  //load the library
  $this->load();
}

private function load()
{
  include_once 'fb/facebook.php';
  $credentials = array(
     'appId' => $this->appid,
     'secret' => $this->secret
  );

  $this->sdk = new Facebook($credentials);
}      

}
```

and the code in base_facebook that i am passing it to is:

```
 /**
* Get a Login URL for use with redirects. By default, full page redirect is
* assumed. If you are using the generated URL with a window.open() call in
* JavaScript, you can pass in display=popup as part of the $params.
*
* The parameters:
* - redirect_uri: the url to go to after a successful login
* - scope: comma separated list of requested extended perms
*
* @param array $params Provide custom parameters
* @return string The URL for the login flow
*/
public function getLoginUrl($params=array()) {
$this->establishCSRFTokenState();
$currentUrl = $this->getCurrentUrl();

// if 'scope' is passed as an array, convert to comma separated list
$scopeParams = isset($params['scope']) ? $params['scope'] : null;
if ($scopeParams && is_array($scopeParams)) {
  $params['scope'] = implode(',', $scopeParams);
}

return $this->getUrl(
  'www',
  'dialog/oauth',
  array_merge(array(
                'client_id' => $this->getAppId(),
                'redirect_uri' => $currentUrl, // possibly overwritten
                'state' => $this->state),
              $params));
}
```

i dont get what i am doing wrong, i am passing an array but it says i am not??
can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you're passing a string, the string '$data' (see the single quotes);

Should be:

```
$this->fb->sdk->getLoginUrl($data);
```

Comment: :) I did worse, it happens